# Human Time Diff, change mins to minutes

Tags: posts, functions, post-meta, date, timestamp

On my WordPress site, I am using the human time difference for the post date.  If you have a post that was posted `59 minutes ago` or under it appears as posted `1 min ago`, `5 mins ago`, or posted `35 mins ago`. Is there a way that I can change mins to minutes?

This is the code I have.

```
<div class="front-page-date">
    <?php 
        echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; 
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago');
```

**Update:**

The same using filter as suggested:

```
add_filter('human_time_diff', 'new_human_time_diff', 10, 2);
function new_human_time_diff($from, $to) {

    // remove filter to prevent the loop
    remove_filter('human_time_diff', 'new_human_time_diff');
    $timediff = str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff($from, $to) . ' ago');

    // restore the filter
    add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'new_human_time_diff', 10, 2);

    return $timediff;
}

echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp'));
```

Comment: If you use the `'human_time_diff'` filter, you'll only need to run `str_replace()` in one place instead of as part of the function call, if you're using it in more than one template.

Comment: The filter callback takes different parameters than the function, so you need to check and return the string as the first parameter. Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/human_time_diff/ for the args list and usage.

Comment: @morganestes yeah, I know but somehow it still works this way it is done above, but I will check why :)

Comment: it works because you're returning the string result of `human_time_diff()`, which is the value that `'human_time_diff'` filter changes. The side effect is that you're accidentally returning the right value, and using more function calls and filter stack modifications than needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use of the [`human_time_diff`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/human_time_diff/) filter, which lets you use your function call as usual, then changes the "mins" to "minutes" on the fly. No need to change your existing code or modify filter use; use string replacement in the filter callback after the time diff string is created by core.

```
function wpse_time_diff_mins( $since, $diff, $from, $to ) { 
    return str_replace( 'mins', 'minutes', $since );
}

add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'wpse_time_diff_mins', 10, 4 );
```