# Is it possible to change X Hours Ago to date in WP Admin?

Tags: date

Is it possible to change "X Hours Ago" to date in WP Admin?

Edit:

This seems to work except for one thing. It says the date fine, but then it says " ago" so it shows "Feb 16, 2022 ago". Any advice?

`code`
function wpse_time_diff_mins( $since, $diff, $from, $to ) {
return wp_date('M j, Y', $from);
}
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'wpse_time_diff_mins', 10, 4 );
`code`

Comment: Do you have an example of where you see that?  Off hand, I can't think of anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it is when you are viewing orders in Woocommerce @KevinMarsden. I think in most places though, but you don't see it as frequently because you normally don't make so many posts a day. Probably comments too.

Answer (score 0):

On the WooCommerce Orders admin page, the order date column is set on line 256 of this file:

```
../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php
```

If you want to change "ago" you can [translate it](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/).  If you want to change the human readable time (e.g. "10 hours"), you can override the WordPress [human_time_diff](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/) function. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/270385/19985) has more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. so this seems to work except for "ago" like you mentioned. It says the date fine, but then it says " ago" so it shows "Feb 16, 2022 ago". If I understand your comment correctly, there is no way to remove ago. You have to translate it to an empty string?

`code`
function wpse_time_diff_mins( $since, $diff, $from, $to ) { 
    return wp_date('M j, Y', $from);
}
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'wpse_time_diff_mins', 10, 4 );
`code`

Comment: Yeah, I think translating to an empty string is the easiest way to handle that situation.